# How to query this table?

Tags: mysql, join

I have the following two tables.

1. nodes
2. attributes

**nodes**

```
id  title
1   test
2   test2
```

**attributes**

```
id  node_id  title    value
1   1        featured   1
2   1        age        13
3   2        featured   2
```

I would like query nodes with attribute title 'featured' along with its all attributes.

I tried to join, but I don't know how to query other attributes at the same time.

Is it possible to make a single query to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a subquery to get the ID's of all nodes with the attribute 'featured'. The outer query would be the `JOIN` to get the rest of the attributes.

Like:

```
SELECT n.*, a.* 
FROM nodes n JOIN attributes a ON a.node_id=n.id 
WHERE n.id IN
  (SELECT DISTINCT no.id 
   FROM nodes no JOIN attributes at ON at.node_id=no.id AND at.title='featured')
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a simple join

```
SELECT  b.title as NodeTitle, a.title, a.value
FROM    attributes a
        INNER JOIN nodes b
            ON a.node_id = b.id
```

Comment: But I want to have nodes with featured set as 1 only

Comment: i meant, featured from the attributes table

Comment: from your sample records above, can you show the output for it?